# Is $\beta^{*}(w_{2k-2}) = 0$ for an open orientable $2k$-manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes, stiefel-whitney

This question is motivated by the vector field question I asked [recently](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364288/when-does-an-open-manifold-admit-two-linearly-independent-vector-fields). Panagiotis Konstantis answered this question for odd manifolds and I am trying to figure out the even case.

Let $M$ be a smooth oriented manifold (without boundary) of even dimension $2k$ with $k \geq 2$. Steenrod showed that the primary obstruction for lifting the tangent bundle $\tau\colon M \rightarrow BO(2k)$ along the fibration $$V_2(\mathbb{R}^{2k}) \rightarrow BO(2k-2) \rightarrow BO(2k)$$
is $$  \beta^*(w_{2k-2}) \in H^{2k-1}(M; \pi_{2k-2}(V_2(\mathbb{R}^{2k})) = H^{2k-1}(M; \mathbb{Z})\,,$$
where $\beta^*$ is the Bockstein operator and $w_{2k-2}$ is the $(2k-2)$th Stiefel-Whitney class of $M$.

Now Theorem 2 of Massey's "On the Stiefel-Whitney classes of a manifold II" paper says that this class vanishes when $M$ is closed. Can we say the same for open $M$? If the cohomology class had field coefficients, we could argue the vanishing as in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/296649/21848) answer and the comments under it. But here the class is integral. Can we salvage the situation using other properties the problem has (such as $\beta^*(w_{2k-2})$ being 2-torsion)?